# Vue 2.0 - How do I get the old selected option value?

Tags: select, vue.js, laravel-5.4

How can I get the old selected option value (with Vue) on updating a form?

My view:

```
<div class="well" id="app">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Room category</label>                            
        <select class="form-control" name="room_category_id">
            <option style="display: none" value="">Attach a room category to a room</option>
            @foreach($room_categories as $room_category)
                <option value="{{ $room_category->id }}">{{ $room_category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach    
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Angular I used to do this with `ngSelected`, how do I pull this off with VueJS?

Answer (score 1):

What I think you can do is have one more data variable, say `oldValue` and whenever the `select` changes, update the `oldValue`.

You can put a watch on variable of `v-model` and in the watch code, set the 
 `oldValue`  variable.

See working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vk52eo8w/).

Sample code:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
        age: '',
        oldAge: ''
      };
    },
    watch: {
      age: function (newAge, oldAge) {
         this.oldAge = oldAge
       }
    }   
})
```